# on calling product link returns "The service is unavailable" error page : Magento CE 1.7

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I am facing an issue with product url in magento CE 1.7.

On calling below url 
" http://www.askforpets.com/dog/dog-bed-crates-gear/dog-carriers-gear/imac-linus-cabrio-open-top-pet-carrier-with-mat-for-dogs-cats-and-small-animals.html ", it returns "The service is unavailable" Page.

I have checked "Catalog URL Rewrites" index and found its already in ready state. I have run re-indexing twice, and have also cleared cache, but no luck.

I am sure length of url is not an issue, since i have other product url with similar length working good.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Rakesh gangani

Comment: Just FYI, Website is hosted on IIS

Comment: Hello guys, I have figured out the problem myself. Issue was with Cache_dir. If any one faces such issue then check cache_dir variable in lib/zend/cache/backend/file.php  file .